# Iterate a function for different values of an argument

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, networking, networkx

I have this function:

```
def run_simulation(nba = 100, maxIter = 10, probI = 0.001, probR = 0.2, probI_init = 0.1, 
                   network = nx.erdos_renyi_graph, netParam=0.1, rep=10):
    r = []
    while len(r) < rep:
        init(nba, probI_init, netParam, network)
        i = 0
        while i < maxIter:
            step(probR, probI)
            nbI = collect_statistics()
            if nbI == 0:
                break
            i = i + 1
        r.append(statS[-1])
    print(((nba - sum(r)/len(r))/nba)*100)
```

which is basically a simulation of a virus in a network. the output is a random number which is the Percentage of Infected Agents at the end of the simulation.
I need to plot this output for 12 different probabilities of infection (i.e. "probI" defined as an argument of the function). These 12 probabilities are these:

```
in[]np.logspace(-3,0,12)
out[]array([0.001     , 0.00187382, 0.00351119, 0.00657933, 0.01232847,
       0.0231013 , 0.04328761, 0.08111308, 0.15199111, 0.28480359,
       0.53366992, 1.        ])
```

I tried this:

[image]

But this doesn't enter each number of the array above as an argument for probI, which would be like:

```
run_simulation(probI = np.logspace(-3,0,12))
```

How can I loop my function for each of these probabilities?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I ask how you're doing the simulations?  Happens to be a big part of my day job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
x = []
y = []

for probI in np.logspace(-3,0,12):
    x.append(probI)
    y.append(run_simulation(probI=probI))
```

For plotting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
df.plot()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One last thing, how would I plot the output of this loop?

Comment: You would need `df.plot` method. You can explore that. If any difficulties, please post a new question with relevant details.

Comment: I know that but, while the x values would be "np.logspace(-3,0,12)", the y values would be the result of the loop. do you know how can I plot that?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You will need to do something along those lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230913/discussion-between-sosaalmighty-and-mayank-porwal).